# Find infinitely many n such that $\sigma (n) \le \sigma (n-1)$

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

This number theory problem has me confused. It is finding infinitely many n such that $\sigma (n) \le \sigma (n-1)$. I know that n should be prime by the examples I have tried, but I'm not sure where to go after I assume that n has to be prime.

Answer (score 4):

$\sigma(p-1) \geq (p-1)+1+2>p+1=\sigma(p)$ for all prime $p \geq 5$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $n$ is an odd prime, then $\sigma(n) = 1 + n$.  What divisors of $n-1$ do you know?